# Prove that if $(1)$ occurs, then $A(t) \in \mathcal{B}$ for some $t>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, dynamical-systems

Consider the differential equation $\dot{x}=A(t) x$ where,

1. $$\|x(t)\| \rightarrow \infty \text { as } t \rightarrow \infty$$

even though $A(t)$ has negative eigenvalues for each fixed $t$. Assume that $A(t)$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix with real, distinct eigenvalues, $\lambda_1(t)<\lambda_2(t)<0$ for each $t$.

Let $\mathcal{B}$ denote the set of $2 \times 2$ matrices with eigenvalues of negative real part such that $x \cdot B x>0$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Prove that if $(1)$ occurs, then $A(t) \in \mathcal{B}$ for some $t>0$.

My try:
Clearly $A(t)$ has two negative e.values. Hence, the only thing to show is
that $x.Ax>0$ for some $t$. Now, $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
         a & b\\
         c & d\\
         \end{bmatrix}.$$ Hence, $x.Ax=ax^2+(b+c)xy+dy^2.$ If either of $a$ or $d$ greater that zero we will take $x=(n,1/n)$ or $(1/n,n)$ to conclude the answer but if we have both $a,d<0$ I am stuck there. Eventually we can have $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
         -\lambda_1(t) & 0\\
         0 & -\lambda_2(t)\\
         \end{bmatrix}.$$

There should be some criterion $\dot{x}=A(t) x$ where,

$$
1. \|x(t)\| \rightarrow \infty \text { as } t \rightarrow \infty,
$$

I have to use that I am unable to figure out. Please help.

Comment: Perhaps consider $\phi(t) = {1 \over 2} \|x(t)\|^2$ and look at $\phi'$.

Comment: Can you please expand? I didn't get you. Will this give me any restrictions  on A(t)?

Comment: Did you do as I suggested?

Comment: Actually, I didn't understand what I should do. I took $\phi(t)$ then what?

Comment: It will be $x(t)\dot x(t)$. Am I correct? If the proposed conclusion is not true then $\dot \phi(t)$ is negative for all t which is a contradiction.

Comment: That is correct.